# Getting "Error: Invalid Value" while adding MX record in Google Cloud DNS

Tags: mx-record, dns-zone, google-cloud-dns

I am trying to add MX record in Google Cloud DNS but getting an Error Message

Error message:

> ERROR
>   Invalid value.
>
> Error NUMBER: d7422936167581091

[image: Screenshot for error message]

Comment: How are you doing it?  Explain your problem more deeply.

Answer (score 6):

Under the preference and mail server field, you've to indicate priority to the MX record.

For example, instead of **"aspmx.l.google.com"** it should be **"1 aspmx.l.google.com"** where MX server address has priority 1.

[image]

*Please check [Step 3: Add the G Suite MX records](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9222085?hl=en)*